# Filtering NSMutableArray based on enum property

Tags: objective-c

I've got an NSMutableArray filled with objects of type "GameObject".  GameObject has a number of properties, one of which being "gameObjectType" . "gameObjectType" is of type GameObjectTypeEnum.  I want to be able to filter this NSMutableArray so only GameObjects of a certain type are returned.  I've got the following in place, but it's giving me a "BAD ACCESS" error:

```
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"gameObjectType = %@", gameObjectType];
return [gameObjects filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicate];
```

Is it possible to pass a "custom" type (ie, this enum I've defined) into the predicateWithFormat call?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

The string format specifier `%@` indicates an object, while you're passing an integral value. You probably want to typecast the gameObjectType to an `int` and use the `%d` specifier. Take a look at the [string format specifiers](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/cocoa/conceptual/strings/Articles/formatSpecifiers.html) for more info.

Comment: Casting to int and using %d gave me what I needed!  Thanks.

Answer (score 7):

```
- (NSArray *)arrayFilteredByType:(enumType)type {

     //type is an NSUInteger property of the objects in the array 
     NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"type = %d", type];
     return [self.array filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicate];
}
```